# laravel lumen installation inside wordpress installed directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel, lumen

I have installed WordPress in root directory, I want to install laravel lumen inside a subdirectory. It gives wordpress error " No Page Found!".
I can access files from other directories.
My lumen .htaccess file code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I have nothing special in wordpress .htaccess file.
What i have to do ?

Comment: i have a lumen directory on same level of wp-content where laravel lumen is installed.

Comment: Apache Server on linux.

Comment: okay please try below code

Comment: have tried but no success.

Comment: your wordpress and laravel direcotry same or differ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132057/discussion-between-vasim-vanzara-and-asif).

Answer (score 0):

Update your .htaccess file. Add

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(YOUR_LUMEN_DIRECTORY)
```

After

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Sample .htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(YOUR_LUMEN_DIRECTORY)

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: I have added like this
RewriteCond $1 !^lumen
same problem. :(

Comment: This .htaccess file is inside /lumen/public/ directory.

Comment: You missed brace (). try this RewriteCond $1 !^(lumen) in your wordpress htaccess file. path should be like /pubic_html/.htaccess file. use default .htaccess for /lumen/public/